# Is there a way to access the CXF message exchange from a JAX-RS REST Resource within CXF?

Tags: spring, rest, exchange-server, cxf, message

Currently we have a a RESTful API using CXF 2.4.2. In one of my resource methods, I would like to process some query parameters and store the result in the CXF message exchange for an output interceptor to use later on.

I've tried injecting the WebServiceContext as mentioned [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/webservicecontext.html), but it does not seem to work, probably because it is part of the JAX-WS specification, and we are using JAX-RS.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest, if using CXF, is to just do:

```java
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()
```

That will work in JAXWS and JAXRS services.

Answer (score 0):

Injecting org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.MessageContext should do too but the code Dan suggests will lead to a simpler code in case of combining JAXWS & JAXRS

Comment: I tried this, but couldn't seem to get the actual CXF message from this context.

Comment: Can you extend this answer? ... i am interested in this approach and  can't find a good example.