# Getting URL of an CXF endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

## Situation

I'm deploying web services with Apache CXF 2.6.2 to a Tomcat server. I'm exporting the services using the CXFServlet and the following Spring based configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
         http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml"/>

    <jaxws:endpoint id="test_endpoint"
                    implementor="org.xyz.TestImpl"
                    address="/test"/>

    <bean id="testBean" class="org.xyz.TestBean">
        <property name="endpoint" ref="test_endpoint" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In my example deployment the CXFServlet is using the relative path /service and for example the web service implemented by TestImpl class is available as http://domain.com/tomcat-context/services/test
The TestBean class has an setter for endpoint and it is set by Spring.

## Goal

I want to determine the address (URL) which is provided by the endpoint test_endpoint in the class TestBean using the endpoint field. The result should be excactly "http://domain.com/tomcat-context/services/test".

## What I've tried

```
log.info("Endpoint set to " + endpoint);
log.info("Address: " + endpoint.getAddress());
org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl ep = (org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl) endpoint;
log.info("Other Address: " + ep.getBindingUri());
log.info("Props: " + ep.getProperties());
```

but the result is just

```
Address: /Sachbearbeiter
Other Address: null
Props: {}
```

How can I get the full URL? Is there is a way without building it on my own?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried poking around the CXF message to see if it is in one of the properties?  I use Camel with CXF and obtain the actual CXF message like this:

```
Message cxfMessage = exchange.getIn().getHeader(CxfConstants.CAMEL_CXF_MESSAGE, Message.class);
```

You should be able to get the CXF Message in just plain CXF like so:

```
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage()
```

See this URL: [Is there a way to access the CXF message exchange from a JAX-RS REST Resource within CXF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750820/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-cxf-message-exchange-from-a-jax-rs-rest-resource-wi)

From there, you can get properties such as:

```
org.apache.cxf.request.url=someDomain/myURL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the url with following code. And you can edit as appropriate to your environment.

```
String requestURI = (String) message.get(Message.class.getName() + ".REQUEST_URI");
Map<String, List<String>> headers = CastUtils.cast((Map) message.get(Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS));
List sa = null;
String hostName=null;
    if (headers != null) {
            sa = headers.get("host");
        }

        if (sa != null && sa.size() == 1) {
            hostName = "http://"+ sa.get(0).toString()+requestURI;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirements. However, I think it's impossible to retrieve the host and port from just the endpoint definition. And as you have mentioned, the `endpoint.getAddress()` just gives service name instead of whole url. Here's my reason:

Let's examine a expected endpoint address: http://domain.com/tomcat-context/CXFServlet-pattern/test

CXF runtime runs on servlet container. The middle two parts (`tomcat-context/CXFServlet-pattern`) are actually handled by servlet container and could be retrieved from `ServletContext`. You can implement `org.springframework.web.context.ServletContextAware` in Spring. The last part (`test` which is the service name) are handled by CXF and can be retrieved by `endpoint.getAddress()`.But the first part which is `schema://host:port` are beyond any of this and it is controlled by host configuration. For example, your service could receive request both to a `http://domain.com` or `https://doman.com` and CXF runtime never knows it when services are deployed. However, when request came, it could be retrieved from request or message as metioned in other's posts.

HTH